# express node.js making a get request to another server from node route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, request

So the client makes a get request using a button on the index page. This sends some information to a route which has been set up as follows:

app.js

```
var route = require('./routes/index');
var button = require('./routes/button');
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/button', button);
```

The request is sent from a client-side directory to the node framework whenever someone presses the button. If the request is sent to 'localhost:port/button', then the button.js file mentioned above will receive the request. So in the button.js file we have something like the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var someData = '';

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    //make a get request here such that someData
    //receives whatever the request returns from another
    //set up framework(i.e. Spring...)
    someData = getRequest('some other URL');
    res.send(someData);
};
module.exports = router;
```

The problem here is that the getRequest('some other URL') within the router get request never receives any information.

Also (as a side-note), I cannot seem to find in the express API as to why we have

```
router.get('/')...
```

instead of

```
router.get('/button')...
```

to access and make requests to the button page.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You want to make a request to some other REST API running somewhere else right?
You can use [node-rest-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rest-client) for that.

Comment: It is not some other rest API, it is an API with state. I think what I said may not work because I am using node as a REST API and so it cannot hold the state of the client call while fetching the data from the other API

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are confusing what is `server code` and `client code` or do I´m missing something?

I´ll try to explain the way it works:

**Server code:**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var someData = '';

router.get('/yearStations/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    //make a get request here such that someData
    //receives whatever -the id parameter- the request returns from another
    //This is express.js
    someData = getYourDataFromDataBase(req.params.id);
    res.send(someData);
};
module.exports = router;
```

**Client code:**

**JS** (angular.js)

```
$scope.getInfo = function() { //here you make the GET call to the server
    $http.get("http://localhost:XXXX/yearStations/Spring").then(
      function(success){
        alert(success.data);//this should be your data
      }); 
};
```

**HTML**

```
<button ng-click="getInfo()">getInfo</button>
```